# How to install YASM 1.2.0 and compile FFMPEG library on mac?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying with FFMpeg for this i need to compile FFMPEG library.To compile FFMPEG Library i need to install YASM 1.2.0.But i don't know any command ?

Thanks in advance?

Answer (score 13):

1. Download yasm source code from `http://www.tortall.net/projects/yasm/releases/yasm-1.2.0.tar.gz`
2. Unpack `tar xvzf yasm-1.2.0.tar.gz`
3. `cd yasm-1.2.0`
4. Configure and build:

   `./configure && make -j 4 && sudo make install`

Comment: what "make -j 4" does?

Comment: @sekmo see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use Homebrew on Mac:

```
brew install yasm
brew install ffmpeg
```

http://brewformulas.org/Yasm
http://brewformulas.org/Ffmpeg

Makes installing a breeze.